# How to validate if a List in a session is empty? JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

As an assignment I was meant to do a WEB page using JSP pages. It should had a **user login** and a **list of products** being shown up on a "index.jsp". After a user logged into the page he would be sent to "index.jsp" to interact with the list of products. Some interactions include changing their price.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to correctly validate if my Product's list in the session is empty or not. My code is recognizing my list as always empty, so it keeps creating the products by default and this makes it difficult when the **user** has to change their price.

Here is my "index.jsp" code:

```
<%

String valiLog = (String)session.getAttribute("logged");

if(valiLog == "false" || valiLog == null)    
{

    response.sendRedirect("error.jsp?cod= No se ha registrado.");
}


ArrayList<Productos> listaProductos = new ArrayList();


if( listaProductos.isEmpty())
{
listaProductos = new ArrayList();    
listaProductos.add(new Productos(1, "Beerus battle figure", 19900, "img/bee.jpg"));
listaProductos.add(new Productos(2, "Goku battle figure", 11100, "img/gok.jpg"));
listaProductos.add(new Productos(3, "Superman battle figure", 29900, "img/sup.jpg"));
session.setAttribute("producto", listaProductos);
out.println("se imprime");
} 


listaProductos = (ArrayList<Productos>)session.getAttribute("producto");

Usuario usuarioLogeado = (Usuario)session.getAttribute("usuarioActivo");




%>

 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Ejercicio 26-04-2016</title>
</head>
<body>


    <h1>Productos</h1>
    <%

      out.println("<h2>Usuario : " + usuarioLogeado.getNombre()+"</h2>");  
      out.println("<table border='1'>");
      out.println("<tr>");
      out.println("<td><b>Producto</b></td>");
      out.println("<td><b>Precio</b></td>");
      out.println("</tr>");

      for( Productos p : listaProductos){     
      out.println("<tr>");
      out.println("<td><a href = 'mostrarImgBig.jsp?codImg=" + p.getCodigo() + "'><img src = '"+p.getRutaThumb() +"' width = '200' height = '200'/></a></td>");
      if(usuarioLogeado.getAdmin() == true)
      {
          out.println("<td><a href = 'modPrecio.jsp?codImg=" + p.getCodigo() + "'>"+p.getPrecio()+"</a></td>");
      }else{
      out.println("<td>"+p.getPrecio()+"</td>");
      }

      }   
      out.println("</table>");

      %>
      <a href = 'login.jsp'><input type='button' value='Cerrar sesion' name='logout' /></a>





</body>
```

Comment: This is also wrong wrong wrong `if(valiLog == "false"` - use String.equals

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: == is for Object comparison whereas String.equals is for the Object's contents comparison

Comment: and why do you have a green beard?

Comment: I see, though I still get NullPointerException... my favorite color.

Comment: check for `valiLog == null` first

Comment: validLog is not giving me any problem. It's purpose is to validate if there's any user on the session, logged user.

Answer (score 0):

How could it not be empty

```
ArrayList<Productos> listaProductos = new ArrayList();

if( listaProductos.isEmpty())
```

Rather than using java in JSP learn to use JSTL.

and then can use

```
<c:if test="${empty listaProductos}">
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13712/reference.htm#WBAPP429

Comment: I get a NullPointerException like that... and I'm meant to use JSP for the time being. On the first try it should create the products, hence products are being added inside the if.

Comment: Well JSTL stands for JSP Standard Tag Library so it is JSP